# python: requests.exceptions.Timeout vs requests.models.Response.status_code 504 ( gateway timeout )

Tags: python, python-2.7, request, timeoutexception, http-status-code-504

requests.exceptions.Timeout  VS 
requests.models.Response.status_code = 504 [gateway timeout]

what is the actual difference between the two as both deals with saying timeout has occurred?

Let us say Service s1 makes call to S2

In s1:

request.post( url=s2,..., timeout=60 )

when will requests.exceptions.Timeout  be raised and in what scenario 504 is received.

Can retries be made for all of those exceptions  - I believe answer for above question might give lead to this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway timeout means the connected server had some sort of timeout after receiving your request(i.e. you did make a connection).  However, the requests timeout exception means your script never connected to the server and timed out waiting on a response from the server (i.e. you did not make a connection).

Comment: I am getting request.timeout.exception in s1 - but still in service s2 i am able to see corresponding entry in DB , which confirms that call reached S2. [ which implies connection was actually made ]

Comment: s1 may not be responding anymore.  I really don't know what s1 and s2 are, but my experience with requests is that the timeout exception means the server has stopped responding that you're making a connection.   The gateway timeout is an actual server reply.

Comment: s1 service1  I meant the caller ( client )  and S2 service2  I meant the server.

Comment: Just going thr the docs :::http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/ -- By the docs in ReadTimeout -we did make a connection

Comment: okay.. then the server is just not responding anymore after connection.